# How to make password type input value accepts only number value in mui textfield?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

- Trying to achieve input type password to accept only numeric value.
- Also toggling of eye icon should be able toggle input type to
  hidden password type or non-hidden number type.
- As of now, when it is hidden, it changes to hidden text type, want to keep it numeric in hidden/password type

```
import React from 'react';
import { IconButton, InputAdornment, Input } from '@mui/material';
import Visibility from '@mui/icons-material/Visibility';
import VisibilityOff from '@mui/icons-material/VisibilityOff';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { registerPin } from '../../../redux/passwordSlice';

const SSN = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { pin } = useSelector((state) => state.inputValue);
    const [values, setValues] = React.useState({ password: '****', showPassword: false });

    const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
        dispatch(registerPin(event.target.value));
        setValues({ ...values, [prop]: event.target.value })
    };

    const handleClickShowPassword = () => setValues({ ...values, showPassword: !values.showPassword });
    return (
        <>
            <Input
                type={values.showPassword ? 'number' : 'password'}
                value={pin}
                onChange={handleChange('password')}
                endAdornment={(
                    <InputAdornment position='end'>
                        <IconButton
                            onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                            edge='end'
                        >
                            {!values.showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
                        </IconButton>
                    </InputAdornment>
                )}
            />
        </>
    );
};

export default SSN;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily manage your inputs inside `handleChange`

```
const handleChange = (prop) => (event) => {
  const result = event.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "");//replace all non-numbers with an empty char
  dispatch(registerPin(result));
  setValues({ ...values, [prop]: result });
};
```

Comment: Yeah, it works gracefully.

Comment: @Clinto_92_Abraham Happy to hear that. You can mark this answer as accepted if this answer totally solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex like `pattern="[0-9]"`

Comment: Tried to use the above props `pattern="[0-9]"` into input but didn't worked.

Comment: try without quotes

Comment: tried, but that gives error `Parsing error: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text.`

Comment: oh, but im pretty thats because we are talking about about Mui specific field, must not be the same properties as input...

Comment: Could we something else for number validation with third party library such as react-hook-form ? 

Will that conclude only number value for a password type. What do you think it as an approach?